# Regarding containing string

Tags: mysql

I am trying to search something based on string input
I have one table called vuln_info.
If I search this way

```
SELECT vuln_id FROM vuln_info where vuln_name="Self-Signed SSL/TLS Certificate"
```

It returns a result as expected.

However, sometime input can be

"Self-Signed SSL/TLS Certificate present" or "machine Self-Signed SSL/TLS Certificate"

what is the way to get a result?

I tried to use like option

```
SELECT vuln_id FROM vuln_info where vuln_name like "%Self-Signed SSL/TLS Certificate present%"


SELECT vuln_id FROM vuln_info where vuln_name like "%machine Self-Signed SSL/TLS Certificate%"
```

I get zero result.

Comment: What do you mean "it does not work"? Do you get an error or 0 results?

Comment: Works for me: http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/af484/1

Comment: Sorry I put wrong question.